# ORDER BY CASE column in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I want to use a **CASE** expression in my **ORDER BY** clause. Is this possible with **Spring Data JPA**?

Spring Data JPA provides *org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Sor*t to handle the sort but it doesn't contain any function to deal with ORDER BY CASE.

I would like to achieve the equivalent of the following JPA statement, but using Spring Data JPA:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN TblList.PinRequestCount END desc
```

Comment: More detail and some code would be nice to help you out.

Comment: I don't think the current versio of spring data jpa able to handle this sort feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [JpaSort.unsafe()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/JpaSort.html#unsafe-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction-java.lang.String...-) to sort by any arbitrary JPA **ORDER-BY** expression:

```
String orderBy = "CASE WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN TblList.PinRequestCount END";
Sort sort = JpaSort.unsafe(Sort.Direction.DESC, orderBy);
```

Comment: Is there a trick to make this work? Because this is definitely not working for me and the documentation doesn't seem to support that this supports arbitrary order by expressions:

`"No property CASE WHEN 'something' = null then 1 else 0 end found for type MyType!"`

Comment: For me it worked out of the box using Spring Data JPA 2.2.6 and PostgreSQL, but depending on the RDBMS or the version of Spring Data JPA you are using, there might of course be some differences in the way it works. Also, the error might be caused by using an expression that doesn't follow the correct syntax for the database you are using.

Answer (score -4):

yes possible
see `org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.class`

and insert on your code

```
yourRepository.findByAnyting(
  new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "property"))
);
```

Comment: It only able to sort by using Order By but not Order By Case

Comment: For example: ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN TblList.PinRequestCount <> 0 THEN TblList.PinRequestCount END desc