# Sort by multiple values in specific order using spring data with jpa specifications

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, specifications

I have a query

```
select * from docs
where status_id in ('105', '55', '65', '228016')
order by
case status_id
    when '55' then 1
    when '228016' then 2
    when '65' then 3
    when '105' then 4
end;
```

How to rewrite it in spring data with specifications?

```
p2 = repository.findAll(new DocsRepository.DocsSpec(filter, type), 
PageRequest.of(page, size, Sort.by(Sort.Order.desc("status"))));
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61040988/11712628

Comment: @Ashish I got an error "No property CASE WHEN status found for type DocsEntity"

Comment: seems like it doesn't work

Comment: according to this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-jpql) it supported only in jpql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59811868/criteria-query-by-custom-order-by-condition) helped me

1. Created **OrderByField** class

   ```
    import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
    import javax.persistence.criteria.Order;

    public class OrderByField implements Order
    {
        private Expression<?> expression;

        public OrderByField(Expression<?> expression)
        {
            this.expression = expression;
        }

        @Override
        public Order reverse()
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAscending()
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Expression<?> getExpression()
        {
            return expression;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Created expression with criteriaBuilder's selectCase function

   ```
    Expression searchedCaseExpression = criteriaBuilder.selectCase()
            .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("status").get("code"), "55"), "1")
            .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("status").get("code"), "228016"), "2")
            .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("status").get("code"), "65"), "3")
            .when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("status").get("code"), "105"), "4");

            OrderByField order = new OrderByField(searchedCaseExpression);
            criteriaQuery.orderBy(order);
   ```

And don't forget to remove Sort.by from findAll(), since we're sorting with criteriaBuilder

```
    p2 = repository.findAll(new DocsRepository.DocsSpec(filter, type), PageRequest.of(page, size));
```

And one more thing, although JPA 2.x supports CASE in JPQL it is not supported in ORDER BY clauses. This might go unnoticed, though, as Hibernate's implementation of JPQL, for instance, does support CASE in ORDER BY